# Generate timestamps for concurrent programs

Tags: linux, unix, time, timestamp

For profiling certain events in a concurrent program I need to generate timestamps. So far I used `clock_gettime`, but I am running into some issues, some of them are due to trouble with the different clocks.

With `CLOCK_REALTIME` the generated timestamps don't seem to match the actual order of events, which means the resulting timestamps mapped to the events does not make any sense.

With `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` and `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` the timestamps are in a meaningful order, but I expected this behavior from `CLOCK_REALTIME` and not the thread/process-dependent versions of the clocks. Further the man page states, there might be bogus results on SMP systems, which I cannot see.

My question is are there alternatives to `clock_gettime` and if not, how could I approach my misunderstanding with the available system clocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to get an ordering of the events in a multi-threaded program. Clock_gettime is a bit too intrusive for that IMO. If you are on an Intel machine, why don't you just insert an rdtsc instruction. Its way more accurate to the cycle and the overhead is much smaller. You can call rdtsc as follows:

```
static inline unsigned long long rdtsc(void)
{
    unsigned hi, lo;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ( 
                      "rdtsc \n"
                      : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
    return ( (unsigned long long)lo)|( ((unsigned long long)hi)<<32 );
}
```

Btw, it will still be bogus on SMP systems as the clocks on the two chip modules can very well be out of synch.

Comment: @Aater-Suelman And what about other machines? I don't want to restrict my profiler on intel machines only.

Comment: Sure. Let me clarify I meant to say any x86 machine, Intel or AMD, not just Intel. Per my knowledge, every machine has some sort of a Read Timestamp Counter instruction.

Comment: ARM has a CP15 unit that does the same. I just google "rdtsc for arm" . You can do it for sparc and powerPC too.

Comment: @Aater-Suleman Thanks, for further reading and applying rdtsc I found this: http://www.strchr.com/performance_measurements_with_rdtsc There are some criterias when the function should not be used. Heavy API and I/O, what could this mean? I use rdtsc to create a timestamp and send this timestamp via sockets. For the sockets I use the boost API, but maybe this is not meant, is it?